# File::Globstar not working for some patterns

Tags: perl, glob, shopt

I am trying to use the File::Globstar module to search for files recursively. 
https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Globstar#EXAMPLES.

However, some of the patterns given in the documentation are not working for me when the path contains a `.` or a `_`.

For example, the search is empty when I do either of the following:

```
use File::Globstar qw(globstar);
my $path = 'D:/a.a/b/c/**/*.js';
my @results = globstar $path;
```

or

```
use File::Globstar qw(globstar);
my $path = 'D:/a_a/b/c/**/*.js';
my @results = globstar $path;
```

However, these work when I avoid using `**`.

```
my @results = globstar 'D:/a.a/b/c/e/*.js'
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in File::Globstar.

[ **Fixed in [0.6](https://github.com/gflohr/File-Globstar/commit/396b320ed56ff6bb69ad1dedea1e2dd76e31f01a)** ]

```
>md f_oo & md f_oo\bar & copy nul f_oo\bar\a.js >nul

>perl -MFile::Globstar=globstar -e"CORE::say for globstar 'f_oo/**/*.js'"

>md f.oo & md f.oo\bar & copy nul f.oo\bar\a.js >nul

>perl -MFile::Globstar=globstar -e"CORE::say for globstar 'f.oo/**/*.js'"

>md foo & md foo\bar & copy nul foo\bar\a.js >nul

>perl -MFile::Globstar=globstar -e"CORE::say for globstar 'foo/**/*.js'"
foo/bar/a.js
```

The bug isn't Windows-specific.

```
$ md -p f_oo/bar; touch f_oo/bar/a.js

$ perl -MFile::Globstar=globstar -e'CORE::say for globstar "f_oo/**/*.js"'

$ md -p f.oo/bar; touch f.oo/bar/a.js

$ perl -MFile::Globstar=globstar -e'CORE::say for globstar "f.oo/**/*.js"'

$ md -p foo/bar; touch foo/bar/a.js

$ perl -MFile::Globstar=globstar -e'CORE::say for globstar "foo/**/*.js"'
foo/bar/a.js
```

Attempts to escape the problematic characters proved fruitless on both systems.

You should [reach out](https://github.com/gflohr/File-Globstar/issues) to the maintainer.

---

You could possibly use [File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Globstar) instead of File::Globstar.

```
>md f_o.o & md f_o.o\bar & copy nul f_o.o\bar\a.js >nul

>perl -MFile::Find::Rule -e"CORE::say for File::Find::Rule->name('*.js')->in('f_o.o')"
f_o.o/bar/a.js
```

Comment: Fixed in File-Globstar 0.6, see https://github.com/gflohr/File-Globstar/commit/396b320ed56ff6bb69ad1dedea1e2dd76e31f01a